# How I am I supposed to "Properly" follow through to the next string while playing the electric bass guitar?

Tags: technique, electric-bass-guitar

So, I understand that when playing (plucking the string in particular) that when you pluck a particular string, you are supposed to follow through, and let your finger hit the previous, or last, string. The problem is that when I do this, when my plucking finger follows through to the previous string, it makes excess noise. It sounds like a thump. Also, when it comes to doing fast plucking motions, I find it hard to follow through to the previous string. Am I doing something wrong. Please Help. Thank You.

Comment: Can that sound be heard from the speaker? If not, why do you care? It's an _electric_ bass

Comment: Yes, it can be heard from the speaker. Well, at least I believe that it CAN be heard from the speaker, itself. I guess that I'm not 100% sure, though Thanks for your answer.

Comment: "Bass Guitar For Dummies" ?  :-) .  I'll go with the answer from droog, i.e. practice until you get gentle enough.

Answer (score 1):

If your action is very low, or your pickups very high, you might be touching the pickup with the next string when you land on it. That would account for the loud noise you're experiencing. So the instrument might need some adjustment.

Otherwise the technique is correct as you describe it. When playing faster, you don't necessarily bounce against the next string as much as when going slower; but you still kind of *graze* it (and need to mute with the left hand). This helps your fingers maintain the correct position by touch.